# Get formula from series of numbers

Tags: math, formula

I have a series of numbers but need to get the formula to calculate the number at position x.

The starting number is always -1396 and every value is a multiplication of 1396. So it starts with -1396 then goes up by `(3 * 1396)`, stays the same for 3 times and then goes up for `(3 * 1396)` again. This will always be the same pattern, how can I find a formula for it?

The only formula I could get from an online formula creator was:

```
x = 1396(z^3 + 3z - 1) / (z-1)^2 (z^2 + z + 1)
```

but this does not seem to get the right answer.

```
-1396
2792
2792
2792
6980
6980
6980
11168
11168
11168
```

Comment: If you plan to program this formula, (i) what language, and (ii) hint: integer division.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog javascript/jquery, ive no idea how integer division works, im not a mathematician, hence I asked here.

Comment: Hint 2: look at how `Math.floor(z/3)` increases with `z` by writing a small program or using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.floor` to make it jump each 3 steps.

```
z = (Math.floor((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 2) * 1396
```